# Importing .csv file in mysql Workbench 8.0.19 by writing a script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to import a .csv file in mysql workbench by writing a script vs. using the Table data import wizard.

I have tried the following script:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE `/path/table_one.csv`
INTO TABLE Datatest.Table_one
FIELDS TERMINATED BY `,`
ENCLOSED BY `"`
LINES TERMINATED BY `\n`
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

But I am getting the following syntax error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`/path/table_one.csv` INTO TABLE Datatest.Table_one FIELDS TERMIN' at line 1
```

Any ideas on what the syntax error might be?

Comment: Change backquotes to normal ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use single ticks and not backticks

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/table_one.csv'
INTO TABLE Datatest.Table_one
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

and please read [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)